# Installation, Boot Problems

Tags: lubuntu

I just installed the latest version of Lubuntu on an older computer. Everything seemed fine until it tried to start up after the Installation was done and the dvd was ejected. It showed a Lubuntu screen , bu then just a small blinking white line, like an underscore, and blank screen. This just repeats over and over . Can anyone help? Btw, I don't know much about computers so basic is better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you were not trying to boot from the cd/dvd again with no disk. You should change the boot order by going back into bios which stays the same when you first boot the computer up. It can be f2 of other f keys on your computer but varies by manufacturer.

If you get into bios try and select the hard disk you installed it on and boot from that should probably be labeled as a hard drive.

If you cannot find an external usb drive in bios then try this even though it is unlikely to be the way you were trying to install.
One other possibility is if you installed it onto an external hard drive connected through usb your computer might not be able to boot from that natively. http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html Plop fits on a cd so you will want your bios set to boot to plop in the cd drive then it will come to a menu and select usb if that is what you are trying to boot from.